# Why does C# use implicit void Main?

Tags: c#, .net, standards

I don't understand why C#'s `Main` function is void by default (in a console project for example). In C and C++ the standard clearly says main must return int, and using a return value makes sense because we can check that return value from an external program and see if the C/C++ application finished successfully or encountered an error.

So my questions are:

1. Why does Visual Studio declare `Main` as void?
2. What's the best way of returning a value to the OS once a C# console application has finished executing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C#, you can use, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691104%28VS.71%29.aspx) :

```
 static int Main() 
 static int Main(string[] args)
 static void Main() 
 static void Main(string[] args)
```

You can also return a (int) value in 2 ways.

In a Console application I would use  `int Main() { ...; return 2; }`

In a WinForms/WPF/... app, in the rare situation it needs a return value, I would use
 `Environment.ExitCode = 1;` or `Environment.Exit(1);`

Comment: The answerer seems to be referring to what you can do, not the standard.

Answer (score 16):

You can use either *int* or *void* as a return type. Thus, simply change it and return a value like in C++.

Maybe it's void by default in order not to puzzle beginners.

Comment: It's void by default because you usually don't need to return anything from Main() in a win app (that return code is legacy from dos)

Answer (score 7):

It's not implicitly void.  As in, you can't just declare main(String[] args) and have it compile as a void function.  The default projects declare main() as void because the default projects don't have anything useful to return from main.

It's also worth noting that C# is not C or C++.  Some of the syntax is the same, but the differences are far vaster.

Answer (score 6):

The reasons behind why C#'s developers decided to have Main declared as void I couldn't say. As far as returning values to the OS when the application has finished you can use this:

```
System.Environment.ExitCode = 1; // Or whatever number other than 0 for errors.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the return type of Main without causing any problems.

Comment: Can you change it to anything you like? Or are `int` and `void` the only options?

Comment: Well, the same can be said about C and C++ in some situations (at some point, `void main` was considered valid by some compilers). Is there a standard way of declaring Main in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to return an exit value is to use.  I say this because non-zero exit codes are usually used to signify some error, typically one that you wouldn't want to continue from.  Calling `Exit` with a non-zero exit value both signals the error through the value and exits the program.

```
Environment.Exit( value );
```

**EDIT**: Note, the context for my statement was within `Main` for a console program.  Libraries and other methods should throw exceptions or return error values.  Only your main routine should call `Exit`.  Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: -1: Calling `Environment.Exit()` is the worst kind of `goto` statement - from anywhere in the program, across all boundaries to termination.

Comment: You miss the point -- Environment.Exit() is the ABEND of .NET.  You call it exactly when you want to exit the program abnormally, with a non-zero exit value, precisely because continuing beyond that point would be dangerous (or pointless).  It's a lot like an early return from a function.  I can't think of any situation in which I would use it that would be better served by creating some bogus logic to get you to the "end" of the program.  That said, I'd only use it in `Main` -- you don't want your libraries calling it, they should throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, that there is still another "box" around your program - the CLR. It will return error codes, when your code throws an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.Exit()` to terminate and return an integer code to the OS.  Alternatively, you can set `Environment.ExitCode` and that code will be returned to the OS whenever your program terminates normally.

Comment: Is this considered a better practice than simply declaring Main as int and returning a value? I'm guessing it is, because this way we can exit the program with an exitcode from any other function.

Comment: @IVlad - I wouldn't say it's a better practice really, just a different way of doing it.